# Scrollable textview black when pressed?

Tags: android, textview, scrollable, clickable

I created a textview that if the text is to long it will make it scrollable. However if you click on it or hold your finger on it, it will turn black like its been clicked. does anyone know the code to make it not click-able but still be able to scroll? thank you!

defined the rest in my xml:

```
 TextView Dark=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Quote); 
 Dark.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) ;
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the selector for the TextView?

Comment: I never made a selector xml for it though..?

Comment: It should still use a default selector -not necessarily an xml one either.

Comment: Im new to all of this, where would the default be? maybe I should just make a selector and keep all the states the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable the TextView (enabled=false) and it will still be scrollable. To overcome the gray text that shows by default in a disabled TextView, set the textColor explicitly.

```
<TextView
        ...
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        ...
>
```